# jquery getscript causing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .load to call content from a section of my site when someone clicks a link. I am then using getscript to load in any scripts that are needed that .load strips out.

However, the content call function is needed on links that are loaded from this loaded content.

I am therefore in a situation where there is a loop being created and multiple executions.

This isn't an issue if the user clicks on one or two links to load content from other pages, but if they do it for several links then I get a spike in CPU, and therefore need to find a solution.

I am not sure why there is this issue, as the script executions are done through user clicks, so there shouldn't be continual execution.

The script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Select a').one("click", function () {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' .containerPlus';
        $("body").append($("<div class='loadedcontent'>").load(toLoad, function () {
            $.getScript("scripts required for loaded content", function () {
                $.getScript("load this script again");
            }));

        });
    });
```

basically the user clicks on a link, this calls the content and loads it into a new container, scripts needed on that page are then loaded, and then finally this code is applied to any links within this loaded content that need it.

This is a loop, but as there is a click element, I wouldn't have thought the second execution wouldn't take place until another click event.

Thanks for any advice

Richard

Comment: What does `$.getScript("load this script again")` mean?

Comment: this script is put in a js file, and is then called again in this part of the script, causing the loop.